# load specific div in modal window using fancybox

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am using fancybox 2. I have manage to load content in fancybox via AJAX. But it loads the whole page and I am only interested in specific div. In fancybox 1 we could do that by adding filter in ajax. But I am not sure how to filter in fancybox 2.

How to filter specific div from AJAX loaded page in fancybox 2?

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        type        : 'ajax',
        'ajax'      : {
            dataFilter: function(data) {
            return $(data).find('#modalArticleContainer')[0];
        }
    });
```

Untile ajax it works but loads whole page, when I add filter then it stops working. This is how I did previously in fancybox 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the latest (https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/zipball/master), then there is a trick to load specific element from the ajax response -

```
<a href="mypage.html #my_id" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">Load ajax</a>

$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

Comment: This does not validate in HTML5, is there a way is JS to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I've achieved this using the `afterLoad` callback to update the content to find your particular element.

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
 afterLoad   : function() {
  this.content = $("<div>").html(this.content).find("#main-content").html();
 }
});
```

So in this example, only content in the `#main-content` element will be loaded.

This allows us to just follow the link on mobile, but load the page inside fancybox on desktop without the header and footer etc.

Answer (score 0):

With [fancybox 3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#ajax) its even more simple:

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="my_page.com/path/to/ajax/" data-filter="#yourDivId" href="javascript:;">AJAX Content</a>
```

Look at the [demo](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/xrKxXp?editors=1100)