# Apply CSS When Only Loaded through Fancybox Iframe

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I have a page which is being loaded through fancybox iframe.. And when it is loaded throught iframe, i want to remove header, sidebar & footer... But it should not hide these three sections which the page is browsed in a new tab and not in fancybox iframe.
I have tried writing some CSS

`#fancybox-content iframe .header {
    display: none;
}`

But it didn't helped.
Is there any trick to make it happen?
Thanks,

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546683/1055987 where you only load an specific `div` inside the `body` tag leaving behind the rest

Comment: possible duplicate of [load specific div in modal window using fancybox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544021/load-specific-div-in-modal-window-using-fancybox)