# Fancybox 2.1.5 Ajax load specific div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, fancybox-2

I was trying to make Fancybox work with Ajax load content and I want to load only a specific div. I tried 2 ways but none worked for some reason.

Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<li><a  href="http://rezerv.city/local.php?id=2&tip=5&s=1 #plan_mese2" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">Ajax</a></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".newWindow").fancybox({
    scrolling: 'auto',
    width: '800',
    height: '600',
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: false,

    'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': {
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            return $(data).find('#plan_mese')[0];

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: no one knows how to fix this?

Comment: You may not need the `ajax` options in your script. The special *class* `fancybox.ajax` should be enough. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546683/1055987 BTW: if you are doing this `$(".newWindow").fancybox()`, your `<a>` element should have the *class* `newWindow` apart from the `fancybox.ajax` *class* (which is not in your code above)

Comment: i have that but it doesn't load nothing just a grey window no content