# Load HTML String from AJAX Into Fancybox Programmatically

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox-3

I am trying to display an HTML string Programmatically in Fancybox 3, but I get the following error: 'Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

[image]

I did try to change the type to 'Inline' and using a href, but no luck.
I also tried to change Content to data without the extra GetHTML variable.

I looked at this post, but no luck:
[JS: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter is not of type 'Element'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196991/js-failed-to-execute-getcomputedstyle-on-window-parameter-is-not-of-type)

I also had a look at this post:
[Loading dynamic AJAX content into Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403634/loading-dynamic-ajax-content-into-fancybox)

```
$('.LinkFancybox').on('click', function () {
  var CategoryID = $(this).attr("id");
  var UserID = "<%=CurrentUserId%>";
  var CompanyID = "<%=CompanyID%>";
  var CurrentCustomerCode = "<%=CurrentCustomerCode%>";

if (CurrentCustomerCode == "") {
  CurrentCustomerCode = "000-000";
}

var APIURL = $.fn.GetBaseURL() + 'DesktopModules/DNNCommon/API/Store/GetProductsForPubCat?CategoryId=' + CategoryID + '&UserID=' + UserID + '&CompanyID=' + CompanyID;

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  async: true,
  url: APIURL,
  datatype: "json",
  success: function (data) {
  var GetHTML = data;
  $.fancybox.open({
  type: 'ajax',
  width: 800,
  height: 800,
  autoSize: false,                         
  content: GetHTML
});
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to display HTML content, then content type should be `html`, e.g., change to `type: 'html'`.